# How do I add a tiny triangle to the bottom of a pop-up element that appears when I hover over a link?

Tags: css

Sometimes when I hover over images and what not, I see a tiny triangle linking the pop up thing to it's image. For example, the tiny triangle next to your username on the center top of the stackoverflow page. How do I do that? Do you use CSS3 for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your HTML source:
    `&#9662;`

You can see the result here: ▾

Or [here](http://pastehtml.com/view/birheq4cm.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unicode character `U+25BC` is a solid triangle pointing down: ▼. You can also finagle html block elements to look like triangles by giving them a width and height of zero and applying special border properties to three of the element's sides. This technique is known as the [CSS triangle hack](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using image or any unicode character. this trick used by twitter bootstrap to make tooltips. the idea is by using a small box under your popup with a big transparent border but only showing the top border, all done by using css.

[image]

check out the explanation [here](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/11/22/css-quick-tip-css-arrows-and-shapes-without-markup/). and a live demo [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css-arrow-with-border-tooltip)

Comment: Wow. It's been so long since I asked this question. Thanks for the answer. +1 :-)

Comment: Currently i having the same problem and was ends up here, then found another better solution. I share it here for documentation. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - Its a [Unicode Symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Geometric_Shapes). The full chart is over at Wikipedia.